# Should a factory method of a custom container return the newly created instance?

Tags: factory-method

I have a custom collection `Doohickeys` indexed by keys. This collection has a factory method `createDoohickey(key)` and an accessor `Doohickey(key)`. Should `createDoohickey(key)` return the new object or should it return `void`?

In the first case, I would use it like this

```
myDoohickey = doohickeys.createDoohickey(key);
doStuff(myDoohickey);
```

in the other case like this

```
doohickeys.createDoohickey(key);
doStuff(doohickeys(key));
```

Which one would you consider preferable, and why?

**EDIT** I believe I have learned quite a bit over the years and that the answer I accepted is actually not really the best one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure the container should have a factory method to create the object it contains - good separation of concerns would be to separate object creation from the container.

Therefore, I think you should have something like this:

```
Doohickey myDookickey = new Doohickey();
doohickys.Add(key, myDookickey);
doStuff(myDookickey); // or
doStuff(doohickeys(key));
```

You are then free to use a separate object factory or instantiate Doohickey directly. This makes it easier to unit test the container with mock Doohickey objects.

If you must have the factory method, I would return the Doohickey, because it is probably cheaper to ignore the return value (assuming a reference/pointer is returned) when it is not needed than to use the index to retrieve it when it is.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, a Factory should return the newly created instance.** 
However like Alex pointed out you could seperate the Repository and the Factory. I would most likely design the factory to have a reference to the repository. I don't think it would be the end of the world of you combined the two into one class just as long as the factory method actually returns the newly created instance.

Answer (score 1):

The example above embeds the factory method in the container class.  I agree with willcodejavaforfood, and this may or may not be a good idea over the longer term. The issue is whether the reduced coupling of splitting the factory into its own class is worth the extra cost.

As far as *why* a factory method should return the newly created instance, it is preferable to decouple creation from containment.  Some users of the class might want one but not the other.  Also, when you couple creation and containment you can no longer (unit) test creation without also testing containment.

Comment: Despite being downvoted, willcodejavaforfood and I seem to be standing on SOLID ground.  For example, page 35 in "Clean Code" by Robert C. Martin seems to agree with us.

Answer (score -1):

This answer is from a colleague of mine. He suggested to have `createDoohickey(key)` indeed return the `Doohickey`; and, additionally, to call it `getDoohickey(key)` instead.

**EDIT** I believe after what I have learnt since that this answer is not necessarily the best one any more.

Comment: This has two issues from a design perspective.  First, the name is misleading in the sense that createOrGetExistingDoohickey is more descriptive.  Names that don't communicated effectively tend to add a myriad of costs.  Second, any unit tests you write will be testing more than one thing (as previously stated).

Comment: With this approach, getDoohickey(key) can change the state of the object. This may be viewed as a side effect since getters (accessorrs) are generally understood not to modify state. If this were a necessary design for some reason (I've seen it many times and may have written a few...) it would be wise to update the method name. The proposed behavior of the method contradicts the most likely expectation/interpretation.